# how to convert string to dateformat and save to sqlite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Mon, 24 Feb 2014 05:18:24 +0000

I want to convert above string to datetimeformat and save to sqlite table. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use below Code:

```
String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

After getting string store in sqlite data base.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html